# polynomial root irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $g(x)\neq0$. If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ exists such that $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)=0$, meaning that, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a common root in $\mathbb{R}$, show that $f(x) \mid g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

I dont´n see how $f(x) \mid g(x)$ is true only by knowing that they have a common root in $\mathbb{R}$. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is irreducible, it is a scalar multiple of the *minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.*

Comment: Look at $h=\gcd(f,g)$, in what field are its coefficients ? Look at $f = h \frac{f}{h}$, given $f$ is irreducible what does it mean, given $f,g$ have a common root what does it mean ?

Comment: Compute their gcd $d$ using Euclids algorithm. Then, form the Bezout identity $d=af+bg$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. In particular, $d\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Then $d$ has positive degree (since it has at least the root $\alpha$) and it divides $f$. It must be $f$. It also divides $g$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Thank you, great explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Let $h(x)$ be the greatest common divisor of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

By the extended Euclidian Algorithm you have 
$$h(x)=P(x)f(x)+Q(x)g(x) \Rightarrow h(\alpha) =0 0$$

This implies that $\deg(h) \geq 1$.

Since $\deg(h) \geq 1, h|f$ and $f$ is irreducible, we must have 
$$f(x)=ch(x)$$
for some constant $c$. Since $h|g$ deduce that $f$ divides $g$.

Comment: Thank you. It´s the same as @conditionalMethod´s comment.